# How to integrate AppService with Subnet through ARM template

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

I am setting up AppService integration with a specific subnet in VNet using arm template and terraform. It is throwing error and can someone help me pointing out what's wrong with the template?

I have already created Gateway, VNet with a dynamic IP address and 3 subnets with service endpoints enabled for `Microsoft.Web` through Terraform scripts. I cannot do App Service - VNet integration, so I am using "azurerm_template_deployment" to execute a specific arm template for this.

The ARM template I am executing

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "sites_uos_aue_web_web_name": {
      "defaultValue": "some-name-develop-web",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "serverfarms_externalid": {
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/SOME-Develop-ARG-App-WEB/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/some-name-develop-asp-web",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtual_network_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "some-aue-develop-vnet-agw"
    },
    "subnet_resource_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/SOME-Develop-ARG-App-WEB/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/some-aue-develop-vnet-agw"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "kind": "app",
      "location": "Asia East",
      "properties": {
        "enabled": true,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Standard"
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Repository"
          }
        ],
        "serverFarmId": "[parameters('serverfarms_externalid')]",
        "reserved": false,
        "requestTracingEnabled": true,
        "httpLoggingEnabled": true,
        "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": true,
        "vnetName": "[parameters('virtual_network_name')]"
      },    
      "resources": []
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_stepupweb_name'), '/web')]",
      "location": "Australia East",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "requestTracingEnabled": true,
        "requestTracingExpirationTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:00Z",
        "httpLoggingEnabled": true,
        "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
        "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": true,
        "scmType": "LocalGit",
        "vnetName": "[parameters('virtual_network_name')]",
        "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
          {
            "vnetSubnetResourceId": "[concat(parameters('subnet_resource_id'), '/subnets/frontend')]",
            "action": "Allow",
            "name": "FrontendSubnetAccess"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

While executing I am getting the following error

> Error: Error waiting for deployment: Code="DeploymentFailed" Message="At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details." Details=`[{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n    \"message\": \"\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to integrate Azure Vnet with Azure app service, you can refer to the following ARM template :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environmentName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "entropy": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, parameters('environmentName'))]",

    "vnetName": "[concat(parameters('environmentName'), 'vnet')]",
    "vnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/8",

    "subnetName": "WebAppSubnet",
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnetName'), variables('subnetName'))]",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",



    "appServicePlanName": "[concat(parameters('environmentName'), 'asp')]",
    "webAppName": "[concat(parameters('environmentName'), variables('entropy'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('vnetPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]",
              "serviceEndpoints": [
                {
                  "service": "Microsoft.Storage"
                }
              ],
              "delegations": [
                {
                  "name": "webapp",
                  "properties": {
                    "serviceName": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms",
                    "actions": [
                      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
      {
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {},
        "dependsOn": [],
        "sku": {
          "name": "S1"
        }
      },
      {
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "virtualNetwork",
                "type": "config",
                "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "dependsOn": [
                  "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('WebAppName'))]",
                  "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))]"
                ],
                "properties":
                {
                    "subnetResourceId": "[variables('subnetRef')]",
                    "swiftSupported": true
                }
              }
        ],
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

For more details, please refer to the [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20348) on github

Comment: thanks @test123 this worked out nicely after some custom changes I had to do for my infra.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has two versions of [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) features. One version enables integration with VNets in the same region, the other version enables integration with VNets in other regions or with Classic VNets but required Virtual Network Gateway. It seems that you use gateway required VNet Integration. You need to include [Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/virtualnetworkconnections) resource to your JSON template.

As I can see, you have a mistake in this paragraph,

```
 "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_stepupweb_name'), '/web')]",
```

It should be `"name": "[concat(parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name'), '/web')`.

In your case, you could add the virtual network (which has a VNet gateway enable) parameter and reference from this:

```
 "virtualNetworks_test_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/test",
            "type": "string"
        }
```

And add resource `Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections`

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name'), '/test')]",
        "location": "Central US",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_uos_aue_web_web_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "vnetResourceId": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_test_externalid')]",
            "resyncRequired": false,
            "isSwift": true

        }
    }
```