# ARM - Create Key Vault via private endpoint using existing VNet / Subnet

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I am trying to Create a Key Vault via private endpoint - "using existing VNet/Subnet" using ARM custom template.
The QuickStart template available in Azure creates a new VNet/Subnet it does not have option of using already created Vnet/subnet.

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/key-vault-private-endpoint/
```

Is their a way to create it in already existing Vnet ?

Comment: [Validate that the private link connection works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal#:~:text=Specify%20Virtual%20network%20and%20Subnet.%20You%20can%20create%20a%20new%20virtual%20network%20or%20select%20an%20existing%20one.%20If%20selecting%20an%20existing%20one%2C%20make%20sure%20the%20region%20matches.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARM template to create a VM using an existing VNet and subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013102/arm-template-to-create-a-vm-using-an-existing-vnet-and-subnet)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT : I am using this quick template but not able to find "subnetRef" Property - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/cosmosdb-private-endpoint/

Comment: You can assign `subnetRef` via `subnetResourceId`. [How to integrate AppService with Subnet through ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737066/how-to-integrate-appservice-with-subnet-through-arm-template) and [How do we integrate the new vnet integrartion with ARM templates?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20348#issuecomment-722170244)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is their a way to create it in already existing Vnet ?

As per above discussion with [Bokambo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662285/bokambo), adding gist as a community wiki answer to help community members who might face a similar issue.

You can add `subnetRef` via `subnetResourceId`.

For examples, as suggested by [Charles Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013102/arm-template-to-create-a-vm-using-an-existing-vnet-and-subnet) and [tom-blake](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20348#issuecomment-722170244):

```
"subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
```

```
 "properties":
    {
        "subnetResourceId": "[variables('subnetRef')]",
        "swiftSupported": true
    }
}
```

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "config",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "virtualNetwork",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('site_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId(resource_group_name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnet_name, subnet_name)]",
            "isSwift": true
        }
    }
]
```